# "A life full of adventures is…" OR "are waiting for us"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

*Life* is singular but the noun *adventures* is plural, so which sentence is correct?

> - *Life full of adventures are waiting for us.*
> - *Life full of adventures is waiting for us.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are talking about ***life*** which is singular and using verb ***is*** for some.

Hence it should be: **Life full of adventures is waiting for us.**

If we were using verb for plural form of a noun then it will be ***are***.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the second one. Because life is singular and that is the subject of the sentence.

Correct answer is: Life full of adventures is waiting for us.

Answer (score 0):

Try some basic variations to get the answer.

> "A great life is waiting for **me**"
>   "A life which is great is waiting for me"
>   "An adventurous life is waiting for me"
>   "A life, which is full of adventures, is waiting for me"
>   **"A life, full of adventures, is waiting for me"**
>   Singular "life" (with Singular "me") : use Singular "is".

Now, this Question mentions "waiting for **us**", which slightly complicates the Issue. Is it still referring to one life or many lives ? If it had been "a house" , then many persons can still occupy it, but each person requires his own life.

> **"A house, full of toys, is waiting for us"**
>   Singular "house" (with Plural "us") : use Singular "is".

In case of "life", each person requires his own life, but there may be some cases (eg husband & wife or parents & children) where the "life" is joined and shared.

> (A) **"A life, full of adventures, is waiting for us"**
>   Singular "life" (with Plural "us") : use Singular "is".
>
> (B) **"Lives full of adventures are waiting for us"**
>   Plural "lives" (with Plural "us") : use Plural "are".

**Conclusion** : Depending on **context**, (A) or (B) can be taken as valid answers or alternatives to this Question.